# required fields: html5 attribute or php control

Tags: php, html, attributes

when I have to validate a form and need all the fields not empty usually I use PHP empty() function. What if I only use the html5 attribute "required"? is it enough or not good for the form security (hacking form)?

Comment: What if the visitors browser doesn't understand html5 required attribute? You MUST also validate server side! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer: **Use both!**

---

### Longer answer

Client side validation can be overridden easily. You shouldn't rely on it. **it should only be used for user enhancements**. A user with a modern browser will enjoy the experience of having the browser tell him that the field is required without having to submit the form and lose everything. **But it shouldn't be your only method of validation**.

You should *always* validate every piece of information that comes from the client (user) on the server side. The user's input cannot be trusted, all client side validations are on the **client's side**. Meaning that the client can control and bypass them.

Comment: really understand..I find your answer very appropriate..thanks a lot

Comment: @Cloud: If this answer solved your problem, consider accepting it by clicking on the large green tick mark under the question's score. This marks my answer as correct, and your question as solved :).

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the validations on both side.
On client side use HTML5 or javascript. On server side code try to check the input value and also filter the input of the text box like this.
filter on Server side:

**Only remove spaces**

```
<?php      
   if(strlen(trim($_POST["input"]))>0){
      your code here.....  
     }
     else{
       show error  here.
   }
?>
```

**Filter special Symbols**

```
<?php
     if(strlen(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["input"]))>0){
       your code here.....  
     }
     else{
       show error msg here.
     }
?>
```

**Basically you need to do on Both side.**

if user off the JavaScript from the browser,your server side code protects u...